# Supabase JSON query JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, supabase

Im trying to fetch single entry from my table that contains and JSONB array of objects. Can I match somehow that array to find the desired result?

```
[
    {
        "chats": [
            { "id":  56789 },
            { "id":  66753 },
        ],
        "id": 999
    },  
    {
        "chats": [
            { "id":  43532 }
        ],
        "id": 999
    }
]
```

I would like to get the object that matches id `999` and contains in `chats` -> `id: 66753`

Tried few approaches but none worked.

I though something link this will work.But no success

```
let { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('xyz')
  .select('*')
  .eq('id', 999)
  .contains('chats', {id: 66753})
```

Can it be done ?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to use the ->> operator when querying JSONB data from supabase as noted [here](https://supabase.io/docs/guides/database/json#query-the-jsonb-data) in the docs.

So, if your column with the array of objects is titled jsonb, something to the effect of:

```
  let { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('xyz')
      .select('*')
      .eq('id:jsonb->>id', 999)
      .contains('chats:jsonb->>chats', ['chats->id: 66753'])
```

More info can be found on PostgREST docs [here](https://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/api.html#json-columns)

Comment: ->> worked, but -> didn't